# More specific exception messages

Tags: c#, exception

Is there any way in C# to improve exception messages?
I'm tired of getting an unexpected error like `Index was out of range` or `Key not found in dictionary` without the most important informations.

I mean, if index was out of bounds, tell me what was the value of index.
If the key does not exist, tell me what key does not exist.

I know I can use `try catch` with more detailed message.

```
try
{
    dictionary[key] = value;
}
catch (KeyNotFoundException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key not found. Key value: " + key)
}
```

However I'm quite tired of this, especially since recreating bugs is not always easy.

EDIT:
I've created simple dictionary inheritance.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ExcDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    new public TValue this[TKey key]
    { 
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return base[key];
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException("KeyNotFoundException: The given key (" + key.ToString() + ") was not present in the dictionary.");
            }
        }
        set
        {
            base[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution here is to create your own class like "SafeDictionary". You can define what happens with `[]` by defining an indexer, so you'll use it like a normal dictionary.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers

Comment: That's why I prefer to use `TryGetValue`.

Comment: _If the key does not exist, tell me what key does not exist._ - this is already existing behaviour of dictionary missing key

Comment: In my case, I want to create code where no such situation occurs. It's not about testing if value exists. ```TryGetValue``` or using ```try catch``` still would require from me to making my own message about missing key. About unit tests, I work with Unity and I'm not experienced enough to use UT there.

Comment: @Fabio, *this is already existing behaviour of dictionary missing key* Yea, it tells me that the key was missing, still it does not tell me what program tried to do. E.g. if you use powers of 2 as keys and you get exception that tells you what the invalid key is and you see it's not the power of 2, then you have errors in the code responsible for getting values fron dictionary. But when the key is indeed the power of 2, the more likely scenario is that value SHOULD be in dictionary, but isn't. Then you look why there is no value in dictionary when it should be.

Comment: Exception tells you what key is missing and tells you source code line number which were trying to access missing key. If this information is not enough than best approach is to catch `KeyNotFound` exception and wrap it with your own exception which provide more specific information you need.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use a wrapper class around Dictionary.

Something like:

```
public class CustomDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;
    public CustomDictionary(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
    {  
        _dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return _dictionary[key];
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("CustomDictionary: key not found in GET. Key value: " + key);
               throw; // could also 'return default;' instead, depending on what you want to get when key is not found.
            }
        }
        set
        {
           try
           {
               _dictionary[key] = value;
           }
           catch (KeyNotFoundException)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("CustomDictionary: key not found in SET. Key value: " + key);
           }
        } 
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. you can avoid the try catch statements by testing if the key is contained in the dictionary instead. Try catch block can be costly in performance. See doc on `ContainsKey`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=net-6.0
2. I would also define an extension method `.ToCustomDictionary` like the Linq method `.ToDictionary` as a helper to make this class easy easy to use in your code.
3. Some doc ref:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers.
4. This is a very simple "decorator" around the Dictionary, and if you need to access other Dictionary methods, you could either just create them, or expose the original dictionary as a public instead of a private field.

---

Alternative solution:

Create your `SafeSet` extension method:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void SafeSet<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dictionary[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            // Here you can just add the missing key without any error!
            dictionary.Add(key, value);
            // of course you could also display an error message / throw your own exception if you want.
        }
    }
}

// Usage:
var anyDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
anyDictionary.SafeSet(42, "I'll be added to the dictionary");
anyDictionary.SafeSet(42, "Now I'll replace the existing value as usual.");
```

Comment: ContainsKey is addiotinal operation. I want to create code where exceptions do not occur. The ones that I get are the ones I try to fix by not allowing situation to happen.

Wrapper, however, is actually pretty good idea I'm going to use.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I understand the need not to add additional operation everywhere. What I meant is, in the wrapper example above, you can use ContainsKey instead of the try catch. You can mix the snippet in my SafeSet method as you see fit.
Glad to help.